# Why can't I see my friends answers in miitomo?

Tags: miitomo

So, simply put, I cannot see my friends answers. This has happened with every single one of my friends. It says they have around 30-50 questions answered, but when I go to look it says "Heard: 2" and "Unheard: 0". I can't use candy to see more or anything. I just can't see them at all, and it's really defeating the purpose of the app. Nobody who has the glitch seems to have a solution, and everybody who doesn't have the glitch doesn't care. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This same problem was happening with my friends and I. We had to delete each other as friends and then readd one another and it worked. We saw all of the questions. I'm hoping this gets resolved in the next week or so and that we don't have to delete and request every time someone answers a question. That starts to add up, too.

Comment: Yeah, so I waited a bit and now one of my friends answers are showing (somewhat) but not the others. Wonder if it might be a time thing since this was the first friend I got.